# Necessary and sufficient condition for a set of graphs to be hereditary

Tags: graph-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be the set all non-directed loopless graphs without multiple edges.

A set $X$ of graphs is called **hereditary** if each induced subgraph of a graph in $X$ also belongs to $X$.

If $M\subseteq\Gamma$, then $\Gamma(M)$ denotes the set of graphs from $\Gamma$ not containing induced subgraphs isomorphic to graphs in $M$.

We need to prove that: **A class $X$ of graphs is hereditary if and only if $X=\Gamma(M)$ for some set $M\subseteq\Gamma$.**

How can I porve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$\Leftarrow$": We have a set of graphs $M$ such that $X=\Gamma(M)$. Let $Y\in X=\Gamma(M)$.
Note that this means that no induced subgraph of $Y$ belongs to $M$.
Now let $Z$ be an induced subgraph of $Y$.
An induced subgraph of $Z$ is an induced subgraph of $Y$, so it does not belong to $M$.
Consequently $Z\in\Gamma(M)=X$ and we have shown that $X$ is hereditary.

"$\Rightarrow$": If $X$ is hereditary, then $X=\Gamma(\Gamma\setminus X)$.
Indeed, if $Y\in X$, then every induced subgraph of $Y$ is in $X$, so no induced subgraph of $Y$
is in $\Gamma\setminus X$, so $Y\in\Gamma(\Gamma\setminus X)$.
On the other hand if $Y\in\Gamma(\Gamma\setminus X)$, then no induced subgraph of $Y$
is in $\Gamma\setminus X$, so every induced subgraph of $Y$ is in $X$, so certainly $Y$ itself is in $X$.